# Vertically center an icon inside a filter list

Tags: html, css

For a project, I need to reproduce the following filter: [image: filter]

But I have a little problem, I just can't vertically center my icons. I have tried to use justify-content: center and to manipulate the values of position: relative, but it just don't work.

Here is my code:

```css
#filter-content{
    display: inline-flex;
    padding: 16px 0px 0px 16px;
}

#filter-nav{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 15px;
    list-style: none;
}

.filter-item{
    color: black;
    font-family: Raleway;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 20px;
    width: max-content;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    padding: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
    border: 2px solid #F2F2F2;
    border-radius: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.filter-item:hover{
    transform: scale(1.1);
    background-color: #DEEBFF;
}

#money-icon, #dog-icon, #heart-icon, #person-icon{
    position: relative;
    right: 6px;
    bottom: 6px;
    color: #0065FC;
    height: 32px;
    width: 30px;
    line-height: 22px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: #DEEBFF;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/1f544e41e8.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="filter-content">
  <h3>Filters</h3>
  
  <ul id="filter-nav">
    
    <li class="filter-item"><i id="money-icon" class="fa-solid fa-money-bill-wave"></i>Low cost</li>
    <li class="filter-item"><i id="person-icon" class="fa-solid fa-child-reaching"></i>Family-friendly</li>
    <li class="filter-item"><i id="heart-icon" class="fa-solid fa-heart"></i>Romantic</li>
    <li class="filter-item"><i id="dog-icon" class="fa-solid fa-dog"></i>Pets allowed</li>
    
    </ul>
      
    </div>
```

I thank in advance anyone who will take the time to try to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these new lines to your CSS:

```
.filter-item .fa-solid {
    float: left;
}
.filter-item .fa-solid::before {
    line-height: 2.5;
}
```